# Print list of document in reverse line by line

Tags: f#

So I am working on this assignment where I have to reverse the document but it does not work as intended. If I run my code on a file like this

```
hello
world
```

I will get

```
dlrow
olleh
```

But what I really need is the following:

```
world
hello
```

So I need to reverse it line by line but not for every letter. I dont know how to tackle this problem so I need someone who can push me in the right direction. I think that I need to do something with my "q"

My Code is:

```
let readFile (filename : string) : string option =
      try
         let reader = System.IO.File.OpenText filename
         Some (reader.ReadToEnd ())
      with _ -> None 


let tac (filenames : string list) : string option = 
  try
    let q = List.map readFile filenames |> List.choose id |> String.concat ", " |> Seq.toList |> List.rev
    (Some (System.String.Concat(Array.ofList (q))))
  with _ -> None
```

Comment: Break the problem into pieces: 1) read the text file by line; 2) load the lines into a data structure, e.g., a list; 3) reverse the list; 4) write the list to the console or a file.

Comment: I have now tried everything that I could think of and yet not solved the problem yet. My thought is that I need to make every line to an element in the list and then use List.rev - Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel said, ...divide and conquer
Break it into smaller steps and solve one at a time
When you know what it takes to solve it,
you can then choose to improve it, 'refactor' it
to optimize
or add error handling
or specialize/rewrite a function 
...etc

```ml
open System
open System.IO

// V1
File.ReadLines "./my.txt" 
|> Seq.toList 
|> List.rev
|> List.map (fun x -> sprintf "%s%s" x Environment.NewLine) 
|> List.fold (+) ""
|> printf "%A\n"
```

... how do you reverse it without a `for loop` ?

```ml
open System
open System.IO
// v2    
let rec reverse = 
    function 
    | [] -> []
    | h::t -> (reverse t)@[h]

let join = List.fold (+) ""

let newLine x = sprintf "%s%s" x Environment.NewLine

// look , I'm a 'compositor' ! :) ♪ 
let chain = reverse >> List.map newLine >> join

File.ReadLines "./my.txt" 
|> Seq.toList 
|> chain
|> printf "%A\n"
```

... what if it doesn't exists ?

```ml
// V3
open System
open System.IO

let rec reverse = 
    function 
    | [] -> []
    | h::t -> (reverse t)@[h]

let join = List.fold (+) ""

let newLine x = sprintf "%s%s" x Environment.NewLine

// 
let chain = reverse >> List.map newLine >> join

// NEW
let readLines path =
    if File.Exists path then 
        // : What if its Binary or something line that ? 
        File.ReadLines path |> Seq.toList 
    else 
        []

readLines "./my.txt" 
|> chain
|> printf "%A\n"
```

[Edit]

Optional string  version

```ml
// v4
open System
open System.IO

// New
let inline maybe test f x =
    if test x then x |> f |> Some else None
// New
let inline ifSome f = maybe Option.isSome f
// New
let inline ifNone f = maybe Option.isNone f
// New
let ifExists = maybe File.Exists 

let rec reverse =
    function
    | [] -> []
    | h :: t -> (reverse t) @ [ h ]

let join = List.fold (+) ""

let newLine x = sprintf "%s%s" x Environment.NewLine

let chain =
    reverse
    >> List.map newLine
    >> join

let readLines path =
    (File.ReadLines path)
        |> Seq.toList

// usage '$ fsi reverse.fsx "my.txt"'
fsi.CommandLineArgs 
|> Seq.skip 1 
|> Seq.head // expecting "my.txt"
|> ifExists readLines
|> Option.map chain
|> ifSome (fun x -> printf "%A\n" x)
|> ifNone (fun x -> printf "None! \n")
```